# How can I uniquely merge two slices with reflect

Tags: go, merge, slice, reflect

Assume I have a lot of custom structs,

```
type MyStruct struct{
  Name string
}
type MyStruct2 struct{
  Port int
}
type MyStruct3 struct{
  Person MyStruct
}
// ..other custom structs
```

I want to have a function to achieve things like:

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
)

func main(){
  A1s := []MyStruct{}{
    {
       Name: "a1",
    }, 
    {
       Name: "a2",
    }, 
  }
  A2s := []MyStruct{}{
    {
       Name: "a2",
    }, 
    {
       Name: "a3",
    }, 
  }
  MergeSlices(A1s, A2s, func(i1 interface{}, i2 interface{}) bool {
                    e1 := i1.(MyStruct)
                    e2 := i2.(MyStruct)
                    if e1.Name == e2.Name{
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                })
}
```

This should results:

```
A1s := []MyStruct{}{
    {
       Name: "a1",
    }, 
    {
       Name: "a2",
    }, 
   {
       Name: "a3",
    }, 
  }
```

So that a simple function can merge any kind of custom structs, including string/int, as long as you have your own implementation in `equalMatcher` func.

The function achieving this accepts two slices and a equalMatcher function(like Java comparator), it modifies the first slices, then merges elements in the second slices but uniquely.

```
func MergeSlices(base interface{}, guest interface{}, equalMatcher func(interface{}, interface{}) bool)  {
    if reflect.TypeOf(base).Kind() == reflect.Slice && reflect.TypeOf(guest).Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        b := reflect.ValueOf(base)
        g := reflect.ValueOf(guest)
        found := make([]bool, g.Len())
        for i := 0; i < b.Len(); i++ {
            for j := 0; j < g.Len(); j++ {
                if equalMatcher(b.Index(i).Interface(), g.Index(j).Interface()) {
                    found[j] = true
                }
            }
        }
        bElem := reflect.ValueOf(&base).Elem()
        for i := range found {
            if !found[i] {
                bElem.Set(reflect.Append(bElem, g.Index(i)))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I got panic:

```
call of reflect.Append on interface Value
```

I guess that this is because `func MergeSlices` accepts `interface{}` instead of `[]interface{}`

I want my `MergeSlices` function works. It is ok to make `func MergeSlices` to have a return value. Any third party package suggestion is also welcomed.

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: Thanks for @Aristofanio Garcia, I made it with have a return value.

```
func MergeSlices(base interface{}, guest interface{}, equalMatcher func(interface{}, interface{}) bool) interface{} {
    if reflect.TypeOf(base).Kind() == reflect.Slice && reflect.TypeOf(guest).Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        b := reflect.ValueOf(base)
        g := reflect.ValueOf(guest)
        found := make([]bool, g.Len())
        for i := 0; i < b.Len(); i++ {
            for j := 0; j < g.Len(); j++ {
                if equalMatcher(b.Index(i).Interface(), g.Index(j).Interface()) {
                    found[j] = true
                }
            }
        }
        for i := range found {
            if !found[i] {
                b = reflect.Append(b, g.Index(i))
            }
        }
        return b.Interface()
    }
    return base
}
```

Here are some tests:

```
func TestMergeSlices_String(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        base         interface{}
        guest        interface{}
        equalMatcher func(interface{}, interface{}) bool
        expectedBase interface{}
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
    }{
        {
            name: "string success test full merge",
            args: args{
                base:         []string{"a", "b"},
                guest:        []string{"c", "d"},
                equalMatcher: func(i interface{}, i2 interface{}) bool {
                    s1 := i.(string)
                    s2 := i2.(string)
                    if s1 == s2{
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                },
                expectedBase :[]string{"a", "b", "c", "d"},
            },
        },
        {
            name: "string success test partial merge",
            args: args{
                base:         []string{"a", "b", "c"},
                guest:        []string{"c", "d"},
                equalMatcher: func(i interface{}, i2 interface{}) bool {
                    s1 := i.(string)
                    s2 := i2.(string)
                    if s1 == s2{
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                },
                expectedBase :[]string{"a", "b", "c", "d"},
            },
        },
        {
            name: "string success test with empty guest",
            args: args{
                base:         []string{"a", "b", "c"},
                guest:        []string{},
                equalMatcher: func(i interface{}, i2 interface{}) bool {
                    s1 := i.(string)
                    s2 := i2.(string)
                    if s1 == s2{
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                },
                expectedBase :[]string{"a", "b", "c"},
            },
        },
        {
            name: "string success test with empty base",
            args: args{
                base:         []string{},
                guest:        []string{"a", "b", "c"},
                equalMatcher: func(i interface{}, i2 interface{}) bool {
                    s1 := i.(string)
                    s2 := i2.(string)
                    if s1 == s2{
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                },
                expectedBase :[]string{"a", "b", "c"},
            },
        },
        {
            name: "string success test with both empty",
            args: args{
                base:         []string{},
                guest:        []string{},
                equalMatcher: func(i interface{}, i2 interface{}) bool {
                    s1 := i.(string)
                    s2 := i2.(string)
                    if s1 == s2{
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                },
                expectedBase :[]string{},
            },
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            gotInterface := MergeSlices(tt.args.base, tt.args.guest, tt.args.equalMatcher)
            got := gotInterface.([]string)
            assert.Equal(t, tt.args.expectedBase, got)
        })
    }
}

func TestMergeSlices_MyStruct(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        base         interface{}
        guest        interface{}
        equalMatcher func(interface{}, interface{}) bool
        expectedBase interface{}
    }
    type S struct{
        S1 int
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
    }{
        {
            name: "int success test",
            args: args{
                base:         []S{
                    {
                        S1: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        S1: 2,
                    },
                },
                guest:        []S{
                    {
                        S1: 2,
                    },
                    {
                        S1: 3,
                    },
                },
                equalMatcher: func(i interface{}, i2 interface{}) bool {
                    s1 := i.(S)
                    s2 := i2.(S)
                    if s1.S1 == s2.S1{
                        return true
                    }
                    return false
                },
                expectedBase :[]S{
                    {
                        S1: 1,
                    },
                    {
                        S1: 2,
                    },
                    {
                        S1: 3,
                    },
                },
            },
        },

    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            gotInterface := MergeSlices(tt.args.base, tt.args.guest, tt.args.equalMatcher)
            got := gotInterface.([]S)
            assert.Equal(t, tt.args.expectedBase, got)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use reflect?

Comment: @Flimzy Because I want this function can accept string/int and other custom struct as well, with business code writing it's own equalMatcher function only

Answer (score 2):

In `bElem := reflect.ValueOf(&base).Elem()` you are retrieving the pointer from the input interface element, not the slice.

Code suggestion:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
}

func main() {
    a1s := []MyStruct{
        {
            Name: "a1",
        },
        {
            Name: "a2",
        },
    }
    a2s := []MyStruct{
        {
            Name: "a2",
        },
        {
            Name: "a3",
        },
    }
    
    // add new value like reference
    addValue(&a2s, MyStruct{
        Name: "a4",
    })
    fmt.Printf("New a2s: %v\n", a2s)
    
    // add values like value
    a3s, err := MergeSlices(a1s, a2s, func(i1 interface{}, i2 interface{}) bool {
        e1 := i1.(MyStruct)
        e2 := i2.(MyStruct)
        return e1.Name == e2.Name
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // fmt.Printf("%v\n", a3s)
    res := a3s.([]MyStruct)
    for _, a := range res {
        fmt.Printf("a.Name: %s\n", a.Name)
    }
}

func MergeSlices(base interface{}, guest interface{}, equalMatcher func(interface{}, interface{}) bool) (interface{}, error) {
    if reflect.TypeOf(base).Kind() == reflect.Slice && reflect.TypeOf(guest).Kind() == reflect.Slice {
        b := reflect.ValueOf(base)
        g := reflect.ValueOf(guest)
        found := make([]bool, g.Len())
        for i := 0; i < b.Len(); i++ {
            for j := 0; j < g.Len(); j++ {
                if equalMatcher(b.Index(i).Interface(), g.Index(j).Interface()) {
                    found[j] = true
                }
            }
        }
        // extract slice
        bElem := b
        for i := range found {
            if !found[i] {
                e := g.Index(i)
                bElem = reflect.Append(bElem, e)
            }
        }
        //
        return bElem.Interface(), nil
    }
    return nil, errors.New("its is not slices")
}

func addValue(a *[]MyStruct, b MyStruct) {
    *a = append(*a, b)
}
```

[Playground demo](https://play.golang.org/p/b6p7AHTuR4j)

[Playground demo with more detail](https://play.golang.org/p/GV1wutN0dmo)

Answer (score 0):

you need not to use reflection to achieve the desired function. That is possible because empty `interface{}` values are comparable.

Thus, a simpler solution involves the declaration of a new type `ider interface{ToID()interface{}}`, that returns, as an empty `interface{}`, the identifier of each element within a set.

I also rewrote the code to someting simpler in my opinion.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type MyStruct struct {
    Name string
}

func (m MyStruct) ToID() interface{} {
    return m.Name
}

type ider interface {
    ToID() interface{}
}

func main() {
    a1s := []ider{
        MyStruct{
            Name: "a1",
        },
        MyStruct{
            Name: "a2",
        },
    }
    a2s := []ider{
        MyStruct{
            Name: "a2",
        },
        MyStruct{
            Name: "a3",
        },
    }

    // add new value like reference
    a2s = append(a2s, MyStruct{
        Name: "a4",
    })
    fmt.Printf("New a2s: %v\n", a2s)

    // add values like value
    a3s, err := MergeSlices(a1s, a2s)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, a := range a3s {
        fmt.Printf("a.Name: %#v\n", a)
    }
}

func MergeSlices(base []ider, guest []ider) ([]ider, error) {
    for i := 0; i < len(guest); i++ {
        var found bool
        for j := 0; j < len(base); j++ {
            if base[j].ToID() == guest[i].ToID() {
                found = true
                break
            }
        }
        if !found {
            base = append(base, guest[i])
        }
    }
    return base, nil
}
```

refs
https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators
Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value nil.

If you dislike this solution because you find it hard to work with a slice of `ider` rather than `interface{}`, i suggest this copy function to help working around.

```golang
/*

    t := []MyStruct{
        MyStruct{
            Name: "a1",
        },
        MyStruct{
            Name: "a4",
        },
    }
    g := make([]ider, 4)
    Copy(g, t)
    fmt.Printf("g %#v\n", g)
*/


func Copy(dst interface{}, src interface{}) {
    rdst := reflect.ValueOf(dst)
    rsrc := reflect.ValueOf(src)

    if rdst.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        return
    }
    if rsrc.Kind() != reflect.Slice {
        return
    }

    for i := 0; i < rdst.Len(); i++ {
        if i < rsrc.Len() {
            rdst.Index(i).Set(rsrc.Index(i))
        }
    }
    return
}
```